# Google Analytics Sign in using Google Account User and Password

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-authentication

I'm developing an app in C# to provide to differents clients use their google analytics info. But the only way I found to connect to get the info is using .p12 certificate or client_secret.json. Is it possible to connect just with user and password like a regular login in google. (maybe with the regular login you can get the .p12 or the json without enter to analytics console) Because I saw in some apps like Power BI this feature but I didn´t find documentation about that in google

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use the p12 key, you can not use the Google logins to extract data.This type of key is used to extract data from the account where it belongs to p12.In other hans if you decided to go through the Google Oauth you must go via Google Login (it's required for the authentication)

You solution here is:

Use the p12 key to connect to all you account (and grant the access to all yours client's account). And them you need to create a fake login and assign a property to each user (this is no the best way, all data of all the client can ba exposed if your security fails)

Use the Oauth Process, this limit the information to the one belonged to the user. (the best option)

more information on:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2